# iAd Warning -- banner view obscured

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iad

I am attempting to implement iAd in one of my existing apps. It works, but I keep getting an error message: ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

Is the ad obscured or could be obscured? Is there something wrong with the code? I can't figure it out. I will admit to being a newbie. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for even looking at my question.

```
- (void)createBannerView {

        Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");

    if (cls) {

        ADBannerView *adView = [[[cls alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];       

        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

       adView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

        adView.delegate = self;

        CGRect bannerFrame =adView.frame;

        bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
            adView.frame = bannerFrame;

             adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);


        self.bannerView = adView;

        [self.view addSubview:adView];


    }

}

- (void)showBanner {

    CGFloat fullViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

    CGRect tableFrame = self.tView.frame;

    CGRect bannerFrame = self.bannerView.frame;

    tableFrame.size.height = fullViewHeight - bannerFrame.size.height;

    bannerFrame.origin.y = fullViewHeight - bannerFrame.size.height; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showBanner" context:NULL];

    self.tView.frame = tableFrame;

    self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: I was having the same problem then I watched this Youtube video and saw that I had to add a banner and wire it the way he shows on the video and it worked for me. Hope this helps! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLpgL6K1vM4

Answer (score 1):

Possible, when iad is being displayed, you open a modalView controller or other views to front. this might lead to obscured error.

Easiest way to eliminate the error is,  removing the banner view in ViewWillDisappear:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [bannerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView];`

Comment: I tried that before and I just tried it again. The same error message comes up. Where should I put it. I tried to put it in createBannerView. Should I put it some place else?

Comment: try it in your animation sequence.

Comment: I put the bringSubViewToFront in the animation and I am still getting the error message.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. I am going to send it to Apple and see if they say anything. But, if you have an answer, I would still appreciate it.